# Menu not showing on Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, appcompatactivity

I followed this guide (https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) to set up an action bar for my activity but I am unable to get the menu button (3 horizontal lines top right) to show.

I am extending AppCompatActivity and using a GoogleMap Fragment which correctly shows below my action bar.

In the manifest I have set:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

as instructed by the guide.

**Menu resource file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always" />


</menu>
```

**Toolbar xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:title="@string/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**onCreate**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    //Toolbar
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    myToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_activity_maps);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("yoyo");

    //Obtain the SupportMapFragment and call onMapReady when it is ready to be used
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

How do I get the menu to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but there's one link on that page you missed:

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html

Basically you just defined the toolbar, but you also have to define all of the items on it and what actions should be taken when clicked.

The "drawable" is what image is used. This one is is the heart.

```
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_48dp"
```

You can create your own drawables through Android Studio by going to File->New->Image Asset, then switch to "Action Bar and Tab Icons". There are a bunch to choose from, including the vertical dots you were interested in.